# Shutdown Windows pc before CentOS 7 powers down

Tags: linux, windows, shutdown, samba, centos-7

Using CentOS 7 I want to shutdown a Windows machine before the Linux server powers down.

I have been tinkering around with net rpc / samba, but I can't get it to work.

Most question I found like mine are the other way around (using a Windows machine to shutdown a Linux machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use net rpc to do this - the syntax is:

```
net rpc SHUTDOWN -f -I <IP Address of Windows PC> -U <windows-username>
```

If you are looking to script this you will need to have the windows credentials saved on the linux machine - this can range from saving in plain text  to kerberos authentication.

Here is a very similar question with some add'l info on the credential side of things:
https://serverfault.com/questions/539699/shutting-down-a-windows-workstation-remotely-from-linux

*Update*

You can create a simple systemd service that will be triggered during a power down (shutdown or reboot) event. There are two primary approaches to a shutdown / reboot triggered systemd service

- Trigger on the service (your service) being told to shutdown. This indicates the system is likely coming down **BUT** it could also mean that the service itself was just told to stop; e.g. by a user. This is the approach used below.
- Trigger on reboot, shutdown and kexec targets / events. I've found this to be less reliable and avoid them. On your centos 7 system you probably have a service (likely not enabled) installed with an example of this - `/usr/lib/systemd/system/canberra-system-shutdown-reboot.service`

**Here's how to create the systemd service**

1. Create a file named (something like) `winpcshutdown.service`. It needs to end with the suffix `.service`, with these contents

> > file: `winpcshutdown.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Issue Poweroff Command to Win PC

[Service]
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/shutdownScript.sh
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]   
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Next,create the target of ExecStop; `shutdownScript.sh`, which we will move to that path. This script will issue the `net` command to the win PC. We will also check to make sure that we didn't get a 'stop' command because we were intentionally stopped for reasons unrelated to power cycling. EDIT: I changed the criteria here as it was inconsistent; systemctl is-system-running will return false if the system state is in transition, both in power down and (irrelevant here) power up.

> > file: `shutdownScript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if the service is still enabled; if so then the stop order is legit.
if ! /usr/bin/systemctl -q is-system-running ; then
    /usr/bin/net rpc SHUTDOWN -f -I <IP Address of Windows PC> -U <windows-username>
else
  #Do Nothing
fi
```

3. Run the following commands to move the files into the correct locations and to start the systemd service

`chmod 755 shutdownScript.sh`
`sudo cp shutdownScript.sh /usr/local/sbin/`
`chmod 644 winpcshutdown.service`
`sudo cp winpcshutdown.service /etc/systemd/system/`
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl enable winpcshutdown.service`
`sudo systemctl start winpcshutdown.service`

Finally, make sure the service is active by querying it with this command:
    systemctl status winpcshutdown.service

Common systemd mistakes -

- Forgetting set execute permissions on the script being called by the service

  - Forgetting the shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the script; systemd won't execute it without it being defined in the call itself ( /usr/bin/bash script ) or in the header.
- Not including full paths for every command - the systemd environment is sparse and you can't assume that an executable is on it's path.

The command journalctl can be used to review the logs / events with systemd and your service.

Comment: Sorry for the tardy response, but I have followed all the steps you described. And the Windows machine is not shutting down. (I had to run sudo chmod - to avoid a permission error) When I run the literal command net rpc I used in the shutdownScript.sh the shutdown is successful